# Find and Replace with ASP Classic

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have an function in ASP VB. and I need to replace the exact word in it. For example I have an string like "wool|silk/wool|silk". I want to replace just silk and not silk/wool.

```
' "|" is a devider
cur_val = "wool|silk/wool|silk"
cur_val_spl = Split("wool|silk/wool|silk", "|")
key_val = "silk"
For Each i In cur_val_spl
    If i = key_val Then
        cur_val = Replace(cur_val, ("|" & i), "")
        cur_val = Replace(cur_val, i, "")
    End If
Next
Response.Write(cur_val)
```

In this case my result would be "wool/wool" but what I really want is this "wool|silk/wool".
I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build a new string as you go

```
' "|" is a devider
cur_val = "wool|silk/wool|silk"
cur_val_spl = Split("wool|silk/wool|silk", "|")
result = ""
key_val = "silk"

addPipe = false
For Each i In cur_val_spl
    If i <> key_val Then
        if addPipe then
            result = result & "|"
        else 
           addPipe = true
        end if
        result = result & i
    End If
Next

Response.Write(result)
```

Comment: Honestly I found the way to do it but they way you wrote is much cleaner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with a regular expression but this is shorter

```
cur_val = "wool|silk/wool|silk"
Response.Write left(mid(replace("|"&cur_val&"|","|wool|","|silk|"),2),len(cur_val))
'=>silk|silk/wool|silk
```

Too bad you allready accepted the other answer 8>)

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help. The other answer were more clear and importantly worked in my function. We should all learn something here no matter what.